# Spark dataframe colums manipulation in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe that has a column `age_job` that is supposed to be split into two different columns (`age` and `job`):

[image]

I am able to split the columns to a dataframe using below code:

```
val tempDF=DF1.withColumn("_tmp", split($"age_job", ";")).select($"_tmp".getItem(0).as("age"),$"_tmp".getItem(1).as("job"))
```

This gives below dataframe:

[image]

I am required to create a data frame that has the split columns `age`, `job` along with all columns from DF1. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just directly select the required columns, without using `withColumn`. Also you can use the parenthesis notation instead of `getItem`.

```
val tempDF = DF1.select(
    split($"age_job", ";")(0).alias("age"),
    split($"age_job", ";")(1).alias("job"),
    $"marital", 
    $"education",
    $"default", 
    $"balance"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You already have all the columns, you actually just need to include them in the final `select`.

Let's break this down:

```scala
val tempDF=
         // this contains columns: age_job, marital, education, default, balance
         DF1

         // this contains columns: _tmp, age_job, marital, education, default, balance
        .withColumn("_tmp", split($"age_job", ";"))

         // this contains columns: age, job
        .select(
           $"_tmp".getItem(0).as("age"),
           $"_tmp".getItem(1).as("job")
         )
```

This should do what you're after I think:

```scala
val tempDF=
         // this contains columns: age_job, marital, education, default, balance
         DF1

         // this contains columns: _tmp, age_job, marital, education, default, balance
        .withColumn("_tmp", split($"age_job", ";"))

         // this contains columns: age, job, marital, education, default, balance
        .select(
           $"_tmp".getItem(0).as("age"),
           $"_tmp".getItem(1).as("job"),
           $"marital", 
           $"education",
           $"default", 
           $"balance"
         )
```

Answer (score 1):

All the above answers should work.
Here's another

`val tempDF = DF1.withColumn("age",split($"age_job",";")(0)).withColumn("job",split($"age_job",";")(1)).drop($"age_job") tempDF.show`

Discretion: It will however add the columns to the extreme end of the dataframe.